# How to make a background blur gradient with CSS only?

Tags: css, gradient, blur

Is it possible to let the text blur over the background image like in the attached example?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the source ?

Comment: @Thomas It's made in Photoshop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to blur one side of the div using CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391178/how-to-blur-one-side-of-the-div-using-css)

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is possible to get a fairly similar result with CSS3 and gradient background. I put together a fast-n-dirty test, where the only difference to the request is that I took a different image as background (downloaded today's Bing background), and that the gradient does not follow the flow of the text as in the photoshoped example.

What I am doing, in as few words as possible, is:

1. Resized the image to the desired dimensions (in my case I took arbitrarily 800px width and let the height be proportional).
2. Set the image as a no-repeat background image of a div with the same dimensions.
3. Put another div inside, which takes all of the height, but only 60% of the parent's width, and added a white-to white-to transparent gradient as background color (yes, 3 color stops to better control the width of the alpha blend).
4. Put the text inside the gradient div.

I don't know how to upload the background picture to StackOverflow, rather than include a link to somewhere else, so I will let you grab some wallpaper to test with, if you so desire. I will only include the relevant html5 and css3 code:

```css
.pic-box {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url("bing-bg.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.grad {
  width: 60%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,1), rgba(255,255,255,0));
}
.text-box {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
.text-title {
  padding: 2%;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="pic-box">
  <div class="grad">
    <h2 class="text-title">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p class="text-box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
      Cras interdum purus sed felis accumsan, sit amet laoreet orci
      sodales. Nunc pretium ante vitae orci ultricies, id luctus arcu
      volutpat. Nulla ornare tellus et turpis pretium ullamcorper.
      Maecenas eget nunc at erat imperdiet auctor. Nulla eros ante,
      porta vitae semper rhoncus, dapibus non ligula. Proin cursus
      convallis tortor, sed molestie erat. Nullam mauris urna, varius
      et efficitur eu, porttitor et augue. Mauris condimentum egestas
      condimentum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you have spare time, you can achieve an even closer approximation to the image in the original request by putting empty div areas above and below the text and trying to rotate the gradient lines by +/- some degree step. This will tilt the gradient line from the vertical type that it is in my example and you can achieve a kind of "wave"-y line like that... If you want to get really fancy, you can try mixing in radial gradients as well and see where that takes you.

Please note: all I cared about in my test is that I could see something in my Chrome browser, so I did not do anything to make sure that it works across multiple browsers. If it is not working in yours, then see how to add the correct CSS for whatever you are using [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp).

Comment: You forgot `>` to `</div>`.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar with blurring on both sides, matching what was done in a Zeplin design.
I put it all together with an overlay floating above the divs, in a similar way to what is shown above.

HTML:

```
<img src="https://loremflickr.com/1320/705" />
<div class="overlay"></div>
<span class="title">
  blog categories
</span>
<span class="Lorem-ipsum-dolor-si">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus vitae dictum eros. Vestibulum ullamcorper lacinia est eget lobortis. Mauris enim massa, rutrum sit amet enim eget, scelerisque scelerisque ex. Nulla mollis massa at odio volutpat, vel congue quam auctor. Ut eu venenatis neque. Fusce iaculis, nunc ut dictum euismod, lectus lorem scelerisque urna, in sollicitudin tellus magna at mi. In non leo non nisi condimentum aliquam non sed orci. Pellentesque dapibus blandit massa at euismod. Mauris ut blandit nulla, vel maximus est.
</span>
```

CSS

```
.title {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 682px;
  height: 104px;
  font-family: Archivo;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #02375a;
}

.Lorem-ipsum-dolor-si {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  left: 100px;
  width: 682px;
  height: 224px;
  font-family: SourceSansPro;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
}

.overlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1320px;
  height: 720px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 39%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.58) 81%, #fff), linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, #fff 33%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.79) 48%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17) 60%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 71%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 84%, #fff 100%);
}

img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1320px;
  height: 705px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

Here is the code I am playing with:
https://codepen.io/BrianLayman/pen/bGvOgbr